# Is a ramming vehicle better off with a shield or an A.I.D.?

Tags: convoy

Occasionally, I'll find an A.I.D. while roving the planet: it lets me ram people without taking any damage myself. (Normally, ramming does equal damage to both vehicles in the collision.) When that happens, I'll usually set up one of my vehicles as a rammer, and send them off to smash everything up-front-and-personal. And then I'm even happier to find a Chainsaw or Buzzsaw to increase my ramming damage.

My two-pronged question is this:

1. Do shields absorb ramming damage?
2. If so, am I better off using an A.I.D. or a shield for vehicles that will spend most of their time ramming things? (Shields will pop up again after being breached, but in the meantime, my rammer won't be much good for ramming.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Ramming is shield-piercing. Shields are great against all sorts of other damage, but not ramming. (Source: me ramming things. Occasionally, ramming things in Convoy.)
2. If you're going to ram on a regular basis, you need an A.I.D. Opportunistic ramming, that you're only going to do once or twice per combat to shove an enemy into a building, doesn't need an A.I.D. nearly as badly. (Ramming does ~50 damage, plus ~5 armor damage. Doing 100 damage to yourself isn't fun, but if you're shoving people into instant-kill obstacles, it's more than worth it.) But if a vehicle is going to do most of its damage by ramming, then you *really* need a way to prevent the damage to yourself.